# Tablesorter two pager : no number shown

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, pager

I am using tablesorter jquery and pager plugin.
I follow this example on my website
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/1/

```
    <select class="pagesize" title="Select page size"> 
        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option> 
        <option value="20">20</option> 
        <option value="30">30</option> 
        <option value="40">40</option> 
    </select>  
    **<select class="gotoPage" title="Select page number"></select>**
```

It showed properly, however there is a little problem.
the second pager cannot show the page number.
It leaves blank
The first one is shown properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a minor bug in the last update of the pager plugin which caused the problem you mention.

A fix is available within the [working branch](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tree/working) (, or you can switch over to the pager widget which doesn't have this issue.

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/3523/) that points to the pager addon within the working branch

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra']
}).tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager")
});
```

Comment: I also want to know that tablesorter can be used in the non-table format? It means no in this format.... 
        <tr>
            <td>Student09</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>

Comment: Sorry, currently tablesorter will only work on tables. I believe dynatable will work on lists.